# Paperclip 2.3.11 throws CurrentBucketNotSpecified error for `expiring_url`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

My setup:

1) I have added a CNAME on my domain to point to S3.

```
assets.foo.com  -> s3.amazonaws.com
```

2) I have a bucket called `assets.foo.com` on S3

3) Model code:

```
has_attached_file :report,
  :storage        => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => { 
    :access_key_id      => "xxxx",
    :secret_access_key  => "yyyy"},
  :s3_permissions => 'private',
  :s3_protocol    => 'http',
  :s3_host_alias  => "assets.foo.com",
  :url            => ":s3_alias_url",
  :bucket         => "assets.foo.com",
  :path           => ":class/:attachment/:id_partition_:style.:extension"
```

I get the expected URL when I call the `url` method.

```
s.report.url
#http://assets.foo.com/study/report/..../abc.pdf
```

I get an error when try to generate an expiring URL

```
s.report.expiring_url
AWS::S3::CurrentBucketNotSpecified: No bucket name can be inferred from your current connection's address (`s3.amazonaws.com')
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:107:in `current_bucket'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:179:in `bucket_name'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/object.rb:300:in `path!'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/object.rb:291:in `url_for'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/paperclip-2.3.11/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:98:in `expiring_url'
    from (irb):4
```

According to the user manual the bucket name is inferred if the `:s3_host_alias` key is specified and `:url` key is set to `":s3_alias_url"`. I have configured my model as per the instruction. I still encountered the error.

I was able to work around the problem by adding the bucket configuration, i.e.

```
has_attached_file :report,
  :storage        => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => { 
    :access_key_id      => "xxxx",
    :secret_access_key  => "yyyy"},
  :s3_permissions => 'private',
  :s3_protocol    => 'http', 
  :s3_host_alias  => "assets.foo.com",
  :url            => ":s3_alias_url",
  :bucket         => "assets.foo.com",
  :path           => ":class/:attachment/:id_partition_:style.:extension"
```

When I add the bucket configuration, the `expiring_url` method ignores the custom CNAME alias.

```
s.report.expiring_url
#http://s3.amazon.com/assets.foo.com/study/report/..../abc.pdf
```

Interestingly, the `url` function generates the expected url even when the `bucket` configuration is present.

```
s.report.url
#http://assets.foo.com/study/report/..../abc.pdf
```

**Note**: I tried various combination of CNAME alias with the same result:

```
assets.foo.com  -> s3.amazonaws.com
assets.foo.com  -> assets.foo.com.s3.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Have you ensured that the DNS is fully propigated?

Comment: Yes. E.g.: The url `http://assets.foo.com/study/report/..../abc.pdf` resolves properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is seen ONLY when `expire_url` function is called when `s3_host_alias` is set. I monkey patched the gem to get around the issue.

Added the patch in `config\initializers\paperclip.rb`

```
module Paperclip::Storage::S3
  def bucket_name_with_s3_host_alias
    s3_host_alias || bucket_name_without_s3_host_alias
  end
  alias_method_chain :bucket_name, :s3_host_alias

  def expiring_url_with_s3_host_alias
    result = expiring_url_without_s3_host_alias
    s3_host_alias.present? ? 
      result.gsub(/(\/s3.amazonaws.com)|(\.s3.amazonaws.com)/, '') : result
  end
  alias_method_chain :expiring_url, :s3_host_alias
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are in a situation where it can not infer your current bucket. The [documentation](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/AWS/S3/Base.html#M000083) says that you can set the bucket name to avoid this error. However as you have realized this wont generate the correct URL.

Try setting the `:url` in your config to the correct value as well with the correct setting for the bucket and it should work.

Comment: This is a bug in the Paperclip gem. I have posted an answer with a patch.